# ASP.NET selectlistitem value int

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown like so...is it possible to have those Values as int so it would be 0 instead of "0"

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.guests, new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="0", Value="0"},
                new SelectListItem{ Text="1", Value="1"},
                new SelectListItem{ Text="2", Value="2"}

            }, "")
```

Comment: Where do you need it as int? Use `int.Parse`

Comment: For what purpose?  Client-side everything is going to be a string.  Code consuming the value can parse as a numeric, but the HTML itself is always strings.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what your code actually does. All ASP.NET helpers like this do is create HTML, which will look something like:

```
<select id="guests" name="guests">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

It's up to you to parse this into an int if you need one, for example in javascript, but when you post this to an MVC action, assuming your `guests` property is an `int`, then your model will populate and post properly.

Answer (score -1):

You should convert the string to an int in your code.

```
 int newInt = Convert.ToInt32(yourString);
```